# How to get always the same instance of UserControl loaded via DataTemplate?

Tags: wpf, xaml

One ContentControl is used to load one of two UsersControls in resources via datatemplate.
It works fine but the constructor of every usercontrol is always called when navigating between them. How can I load always the same instance of the usercontrol (one instance for UserControl1 and one instance for Usercontrol2). I know that the tabcontrol can achieve that but how I can do it in my scenario without tabcontrol.

**Resources:**

```
<UserControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="UserControl1">
            <local:UserControl1 />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="UserControl2">
            <local:UserControl2 />
        </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

**ContentControl:**

```
<ContentControl x:Name="ContentControl" Background="White">
                    <ContentControl.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CurrentView, 
                                   ElementName=UserControl1}" Value="UserControl1">
                                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource UserControl1}" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CurrentView, ElementName=UserControl2}" Value="UserControl2">
                                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource UserControl2}" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </ContentControl.Style>
</ContentControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I load always the same instance of the usercontrol (one instance for UserControl1 and one instance for Usercontrol2)

You can hold the instances as Resources and host them inside a ContentPresenter, instead of creating a new instance everytime the DataTemplate is used:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <local:UserControl1 x:Key="UserControl1Instance" />
    <local:UserControl2 x:Key="UserControl2Instance" />

    <DataTemplate x:Key="UserControl1">
        <ContentPresenter Content="{StaticResource UserControl1Instance}" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="UserControl2">
        <ContentPresenter Content="{StaticResource UserControl2Instance}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I load always the same instance of the usercontrol

You should not be concerned about that. There's nothing in your post that explains why you are concerned about the constructor being called multiple times, but that should be a complete non-issue. If it's an issue, then you have something wrong with your design.

"View" objects, such as windows, user controls, and indeed every `UIElement` that goes into presenting the program's state to the user, should not have *any* operations within them except that strictly needed to present the state to the user. WPF will instantiate and discard your specific instances as needed to handle the current state of the program. If it's in any way a problem for more than one instance of a user control to exist at a time, or for more than one instance to be created and/or discarded over the course of running the program, then the design of the program is fundamentally broken and should be fixed.

If you run into any problems trying to accomplish that, of course feel free to post a question about that. Be sure to include a good [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), along with any details about what specifically you need help with.

And of course, to start with, you should read everything you can find on [the MVVM design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93viewmodel), if you haven't already. WPF has a steep learning curve when using the framework correctly, but it's *even harder* to use when you're not using it correctly.